# Asp.Net Crystal Reports Returns blank Data on Print and Export buttons

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am using crystal reports in my asp.net application with vs 2010, It is working fine to print and export reports when I used the code on Page_Load event, but when I use the same code on a button click event, it returns empty data or blank report when I send it to printer or export to hard drive by using CR Viewer built-in buttons. I also used IsPotBack option on the page load and button click event before calling the code. But still failed to solve the problem.
Below is my source code for accessing the report:

```
    Dim CN As New SqlConnection("connectionstring...")
    CN.Open()
    Dim ds As New DS_App_Profile.V_App_ProfileDataTable()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * from TblApplicants where Applicant_Id=@id", CN)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("id", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value =          Me.ComboBox1.SelectedValue
     Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
     adp.Fill(ds)
      'object of Report RptApplicantsByID
     Dim rep As New RptApplicantsByID()
     rep.SetDataSource(DirectCast(ds, DataTable))
     Me.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rep
     Me.CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind()
```

Comment: So the above code works under page_load but not under your button? Can you post the whole code for your button, please?

Comment: I used the same code on button_click, the report is showing data very well but when I export or print report, it sends blank report on by using the code on button_click event. I mean When I used the above code on page_load it can be viewed printed/exported but by using it on a button click, it only viewed the report, can't be exported or printed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed the same code under crystal Report Viewer Load  event and it start working.